# Complexe of vector bundle using Koszul Complex

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a compact Kahler manifold and $i:Y\hookrightarrow X$ a closed submanifold (or subvariety). Let $E\to Y$ be a holomorphic vector bundle on $Y$. The sheaf $i_*\mathcal{O}(E)$ on $X$ is coherent and we can resolve it a complex of holomorphic vector bundle.

I heard that we can construct this resolution using the so called Koszul complex. Is there a reference where this is explained ?

Comment: What is $F$? Anyway, Koszul complex, indeed, gives a resolution for the trivial vector bundle under the assumption that $Y$ is the zero locus of a regular global section of a vector bundle on $X$.

Comment: @Sasha sorry I meant $E$ (fixed). I do assume that $Y$ can be realize as the zero locus of a section of a vector bundle, say $F$ on $X$.

Comment: Then the Koszul complex looks like $$0 \to \wedge^rF^\vee \to \wedge^{r-1}F^\vee \to \dots \to F^\vee \to \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_Y \to 0.$$

Comment: This is a resolution of $\mathcal{O}_Y$ over $Y$ right? I would like to know if I can get a resolution of $i_*\mathcal{O}_Y\to X$ and then a resolution of $i_*E\to X$. Is there a similar construction?

Comment: This is a resolution of $\mathcal{O}_Y$ over $X$. If $E$ can be realized as the restriction of a vector bundle $E'$ on $X$, you can tensor the above sequence with $E'$ to get a resolution of $E' \otimes \mathcal{O}_Y \cong i_*i^*E' \cong i_*E$.

Comment: Ok. But I would like to resolve a vector bundle on $Y$ which does not come from a vector bundle on $X$

Comment: Then, I am afraid, Koszul complex does not help.